# Where can I find/get basic information about Hinduism on the web?

Tags: resource

I think getting information and knowledge about Hinduism is very useful for knowing and learning about Hinduism. So, I want to ask:

Where can I find/get basic information and knowledge about Hinduism on the web?

Note: Recommend the resources that are written by Indian academics rather than Western or Christian .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Few places to get information & knowledge about Hinduism,

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism)*
- [Hindupedia](http://hindupedia.com)
- [Bharatkosh](http://bharatdiscovery.org/india/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%80:%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%82_%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE) (Hindi)
- [Veda.Wikidot](http://veda.wikidot.com)
- [Hinduwebsite](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/hinduindex.asp)
- [Dharma Wiki](https://dharmawiki.org/index.php/Main_Page)

---

<sup>*Also consider [General disclaimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:General_disclaimer) & About [trusting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Ten_things_you_may_not_know_about_Wikipedia#We_do_not_expect_you_to_trust_us).
 May be considerable that [Most part are written by Western Christian academics](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13626/where-are-the-three-levels-of-reality-described#comment32678_13626).</sup>

Comment: Add [Indian Scriptures](http://www.indianscriptures.com/) also.

Comment: Astrojyoti.com ,Hindupedia.com.

Comment: We can't trust Wikipedia always.

Comment: @TheDestroyer but we are recognizing it as very helpful than others! and how about I think mostly trustful

Comment: Wikipedia is ideologically one-sided (mostly secular and marxist interventionist). See https://www.hindujagruti.org/news/81013.html

Comment: @Pandya Many of the links are removed in latest edit. May I know why? [link](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/10600/revisions). Also, please explain your edits on a wiki post.

Comment: @Mr_Green [Clarification to The Destroyer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/conversation/clarification-to-the-destroyer)

Comment: @Pandya: Searching for lectures of Swami Vivekananda at World Parliament of Religions would also be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.himalayanacademy.com/readlearn has got lot of basic Hinduism articles.  Advance stuff is all sectarian though.  But articles which specifically talk about Hinduism are not.

Answer (score 1):

www.satsangh.org is a website which has many blogs on Hinduism. You could visit that.

You could also visit www.shrinimishamba.org There are lot of articles in the teachings section of the page. Many scriptures are discussed here. Currently they are running a series on Shri Guru Gita from Skanda Purana.